How to change carousel items' width not losing center property?
Wondering why the carousel loses the text-align property (value 'center') when changing the carousel item's width. I'm new to writing CSS, and I need to change the carousel item's width in the media screen and (max-width:480px). I'm just stuck.  Big thanks in advance! I tried to change the items' width but the carousel is losing text-align property (value 'center'). P.S Don't judge me too strictly. It's my first site
     <section class="section-more" id="services">
            <div class="more-header">
                <img class="more-image" src="img/flowers (2).jpg" alt="">
                <p class="text-more">I help agencies and brands to <br> turn their ideas into designs. Great <br> designs
                    and a healthy freelance relationship.</p>
            </div>
    
    
    
            <div class="carousel">
                <a class="carousel-item" href="#">
                    <div class="testi">
                        <div class="img-area">
                            <img src="img/web design svg.svg" alt="Design">
                        </div>
                        <p>Webdesign</p>
                        <h3>Beautiful and elegant designs with interfaces that are efficient, intuitive and pleasant to
                            use for the users.</h3>
                    </div>
    
                </a>
    
                <a class="carousel-item" href="#">
                    <div class="testi">
                        <div class="img-area">
                            <img src="img/web development  svg.svg" alt="Design">
                        </div>
                        <p>Development</p>
                        <h3>Custom web development tailored to your specifications, designed to provide a flawless user
                            experience.</h3>
                    </div>
    
                </a>
    
                <a class="carousel-item" href="#">
                    <div class="testi">
                        <div class="img-area">
                            <img src="img/mobile app svg.svg" alt="Design">
                        </div>
                        <p>Mobile App</p>
                        <h3>Design and transform website projects into mobile apps to provide a seamless user
                            experience.
                        </h3>
                    </div>
    
                </a>
    
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('.carousel').carousel({
                            padding: 200
                        });
                        autoplay();
                        function autoplay() {
                            $('.carousel').carousel('next');
                            setTimeout(autoplay, 5800)
                        }
                    });
    
                </script>
            </div>
        </section>

And css
.section-more {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #e3e1df;
  height: 100vh;
}

.more-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.text-more {
  color: #434c3e;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 36px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 158px;
}

.carousel {
  height: 600px;
  perspective: 250px;
  margin-top: -50px auto;
}

.carousel .carousel-item {
  width: 450px;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 50px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.img-area {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: inset 8px #88a2a5;
}

.img-area img {
  width: 99%;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.testi p {
  color: #434c3e;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 1.9;
}

.testi h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #434c3e;
}


Sometimes they are inhereted from a class.  You can also add the !important tag to css to force it to over-ride this when you set something, such as, text-align:center !important;  Alas we can't advertise our sites through questions so you might want to just take a screenshot and post it to the question to avoid violations to questions.  Otherwise the site would get flooded with SEO attempts instead of help.

Thank you for your advise! I've tried the !Important tag, it didn't help(

I used margin: 0 auto

one thing is you have this : img/mobile app svg.svg , i don't think you ever want a space in a web located file name, it might not show up.   What happens if you add body(text-alight:center !important;}  Ah of course if you have margin or padding it can throw your text around too.

Body(text-align: center ! Important;) effects some blocks of the site, but not the carousel

what if you add it to both of these .carousel .carousel-item ?

It does nothing
